# Calculate the center of adjacent values in an array

Tags: arrays, r, vector

I created an array of values:

```
binBorder=exp(0:5)
# 1.000000   2.718282   7.389056  20.085537  54.598150 148.413159
```

which gives me an array with the length 6 in this case. Now I want to create a second array, which contains the the number which is exactly between thos two numbers. This should give an array of the size of five in this case and contain the values:

```
 1.000000 - ( 1.000000 -   2.718282) / 2
 2.718282 - ( 2.718282 -   7.389056) / 2
 7.389056 - ( 7.389056 -  20.085537) / 2
20.085537 - (20.085537 -  54.598150) / 2
54.598150 - (54.598150 - 148.413159) / 2
```

Is there a built-in function for such things? I need it for the calculation of the bin center (that should be a common problem). Or is the following code the "easiest solution"?

```
> bb1 = exp(0:4)
> bb2 = exp(1:5)
> bb = bb1 + ((bb2 - bb1) / 2)
> bb
```

I'm a newcomer to R so I'm not sure how problems are generally solved. Is it more built-in functions or constructing things like the solution that I made up?

Thanks for your help,

Sven

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution can be rewritten using subsetting to avoid the intermediate variables:

```
(binBorder[1:5]+binBorder[-1])/2
[1]   1.859141   5.053669  13.737297  37.341843 101.505655
```

In fact, more generally you could write the following function:

```
midPoints <- function(x){
  (x[-length(x)]+x[-1])/2
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The function `filter` does what you are asking for.  When used in the following way, it calculates the 2-period moving average:

```
filter(binBorder, c(0.5, 0.5), sides=1)
Time Series:
Start = 1 
End = 6 
Frequency = 1 
[1]         NA   1.859141   5.053669  13.737297  37.341843 101.505655
```

The only (slight) downside of filter is that it returns a value of class `ts` (for time series).

You can avoid that by calling `convolve`:

```
convolve(binBorder, c(0.5, 0.5), type="filter")
[1]   1.859141   5.053669  13.737297  37.341843 101.505655
```

Comment: Nice answer, but I think `convolve` will carry a lot of overhead for the task.

Answer (score 1):

Isn't this easily handled by diff()?

```
binBorder <- exp(0:5)
binBorder[1:5] + diff(binBorder)/2
```